# symfony2.3 routing doesn't work on prod env

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

I'm trying to create a /contact route on my website  using symfony on windows environment.
I added in the `routing.yml` file the routes like this:

```
fstn_venice_homepage:
resource: "@FstnVeniceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /

fstn_venice_contact:
pattern:   /contact
defaults:  { _controller: FstnVeniceBundle:Contact:send }
```

I have enabled the prod env :`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`
Trying to execute the page on **prod_env**: `http://localhost/fstn/web/app_dev.php/contact` return an 404 error but in **dev_env** it displays the contact page correctly. 
So that I try to debug the routes by:  `php app/console router:debug -e=prod`
and I get this:

`Name                            Method   Scheme   Host    Path
fstn_venice_homepage             ANY      ANY      ANY      /
fstn_venice_contact              ANY      ANY      ANY     /contact`

I even try to clear the cache by using the Command line :

`php .\app\console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` and it doesn't display any errors but no luck to display contact page on prod environment.
How can I fix this problem?

--edit---
I found the source of my error, actually I should use this path to work in prod env:http://localhost/fstn/web/app.php/contact but I used before http://localhost/fstn/web/contact to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying the kernel you want a prod environement `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` you tell him to forbid access to the dev url `http://localhost/fstn/web/app_dev.php/contact`.

If you want to access to the prod url, replace `app_dev.php` with `app.php`.
You can still let the kernel env configuration to dev, and test in prod environement. After every change, don't forget to clear your cache, and `chmod` it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache, It will be fine.